# Width: 100% Without Scrollbars

Tags: css, layout, width, overflow

I'm trying to make a part of my webpage that fit the width of the browser, for this I'm using `width: 100%`, the problem is that it shows scrollbars and I can't use `overflow-x: hidden;` because it will make some of the content hidden, so how I can fix this?

```
#news {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-user-select: text;
}
```

Comment: Please show some code. Why does it show scrollbars?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

That's because you're using `position: absolute`.

Instead of using:

```
width: 100%; margin-right: 10px; margin-left: 10px
```

you should use:

```
left: 10px; right: 10px
```

That will make your element take the full width available, with `10px` space on the left and right.

Comment: This is an excellent solution, and it works for <div>, but not for all elements. However, other elements can be children of a <div> configured this way, and then use style="width: 100%;" to achieve the goal. The <div> may also need style settings for margins and padding (zero) to achieve full width for the contained item.

Answer (score 4):

You have to remove the `margins` on the `#news` item

```
#news {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 10px;  /*REMOVE THIS*/
    margin-left: 10px;   /*REMOVE THIS*/
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-user-select: text;
}
```

If this doesn't work, you might have `margin` and `padding` set on the element itself.  Your `div` - if that is what you are using - might have styles applied to it, either in your stylesheet or base browser styles. To remove those, set the margins specifically to `0` and add `!important` as well.

```
#news {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 !important; 
    padding: 0 !important;
    -webkit-user-select: text;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with a absolute positioned element, and I wanted to use width 100%. This is the approach I used and it solved my problem:

`box-sizing=border-box`

Otherwise I always had a little content and padding pushing past the scroll bar.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you have margins set that will make the div wider than the 100%; hence the scrollbars.

If you can rid yourself of margins do it!  However, often you'll want the margins.  In this case, wrap the whole thing in a container div and set margins to 0 with width at 100%.

Comment: I've removed the margins and I still have scrollbars

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have set the width to 100%, but there are also margins that force the width to expand beyond that.

Try googling for "css flexible ( two/three-collumn) layouts".

Here's an example,

```
<div id="cont">
   <div id="menu"></div>
   <div id="main"></div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

and the css

```
#menu{
  float:left;
  height:100%;
  width:200px;
}
#main{
  padding-left:200px;
}
.clear{clear:both;}
```

The `#menu div`, will be aligned to the left and have a static width of `200px`.
The `#main div`, will "begin" below `#main`, but because of it's `200px padding` (can also be margin) its content and child elements will start - where `#menu` ends.

We must not set `#main` to a percent width, (for example `100%`) because the 200 pixels of left padding will be added to that, and break the layout by adding scrollbars to the X axis.