# Full screen width for child element of a non full screen width parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This question builds upon [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31391459/how-can-i-expand-a-child-div-to-100-screen-width-if-the-container-div-is-smalle), where in order to apply full screen width to a child of a non full width parent element, the following rule is used on the child element:

```
width: 100vw;
margin-left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
```

As shown in [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k3nvkL35/), this solution doesn't work in the presence of a vertical scrollbar though: `100vw` doesn't take the scrollbar into account and hence the child element ends up being wider than the screen (note: works perfectly without scrollbar).

Is there a way to solve this problem so that the child element takes exactly full screen width? If not in pure CSS then with JS?

Note: an `overflow` rule on `body` isn't acceptable in my case as I need the child to fill the exact width of the screen.

Comment: Here is a jQuery approach - https://jsfiddle.net/vt5cych9/

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/k3nvkL35/4/

One of the issues you'll come across with the solution here is that I believe scrollbar widths are not universal, and so you may need to implement some conditional logic to affect width/margin based on that.

That being said, you may find this useful. The function below will check to see if the document has a vertical scrollbar by comparing the document's height to the window's height. Based on the existence of said scrollbar, it will modify the child's width and margins to fit the window.

Again, it likely requires tweaking, though it should provide a decent foundation.

```js
function adjustWidth() {
    if ($(document).height() > $(window).height()) {
        $(".child").css({
            "width": "calc(100vw - 18px)",
            "margin-left": "calc(-50vw + 50% + 9px)"
        });
    } else {
     $(".child").css({
         "width": "",
            "margin-left": ""
        })
    }
}

$(window).resize(adjustWidth).trigger("resize");
```

```css
.parent {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 3px solid green;
}

.child {
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    width: 100vw;
    margin-left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        content
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I was just thinking that scrollbar widths are not universal across browsers so it seems like there would be no way to implement this without somekind of conditional logic adjusting the width to each scrollbar size.  interesting that there isn't a more obvious solution out there?

Comment: It's unfortunate, though there isn't a pure CSS solution that I know of, and to be brutally honest I'm not super proud of the solution I've provided. It just seems a bit janky, and despite the best cleanup efforts, there doesn't seem to be an elegant method of compensating for scrollbars - at least, not one I'm aware of. But good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Since the parent isn't positioned in any way, then the child can be positioned absolutely. No messing with `calc` or otherwise, works everywhere.

```
.child {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```

Here is a working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/vgbr6qw2/

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://jsfiddle.net/m1L6pfwm/2/) solution, which was sourced by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40090245/8085668) guy, but I don't know who originally did it. I haven't fully tested it, so it may not work in all browsers. I know the `vw` unit isn't supported in IE8, as if anyone cares.

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
.wrapper {
  width:100%;
  max-width:400px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:pink;
  /* margin is for display purposes on stack overflows fullscreen snippet view */
  margin-top:80px;
}
.full-width {
  width:100vw;
  margin-left:-50vw;
  left:50%;
  background:red;
  position:relative;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span>Hi. I'm a paragraph.</span>
  <div class="full-width">
      <p>You aint no paragraph, sucka!</p>
  </div>
  <strong>Be quiet, you weak losers.</strong>
</div>
```